# Two-way Entity Reference?

Tags: entities

I'm building a site for a school, with several content types:

- A **Class** holds the general info about a class: description, tuition, etc. One field in the Class type is an Entity Reference for an Instructor.
- An **Instructor** is the teacher of a Class.

When adding a new Class, the user will add an Instructor using the Entity Reference field (as an "autocomplete" widget). However, I also want the list of Instructors to link to the Classes each one teaches. How do I do this without having to enter the data on both the Class page *and* the Instructors page?

Comment: If you use Views you can add a reversed relationship and output the desired fields.

Comment: Is that the "Referencing Entity" in Relationships?

Comment: Yup, that is the one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually found a great tutorial which explains in detail how to do this: [Using Views Contextual Filter and Relationship to display reference on referenced node](https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004).

Now, I have another, related, question: What if I want to include the Classes taught by the Instructor on the "list of instructors" page (which is a View)?

Comment: Please don't include a question in an answer, but post a new question instead. That way we keep question and answer together for future reference.